# I connected the segue, but the data value is not coming in. [Swift]

Tags: ios, segue

caution!!!! This article has a lot of pictures attached to make it easier to understand. We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused. I tried to solve it for a few days by myself, but I couldn't solve it, so I posted it. Sorry. I really don't know which is the problem.

I inserted `Container View` in `ViewController` and `embed` the `Container View` into `TableViewController`.

I'll attach a simple example picture to make it easier to understand.[image]

In the project I am making, I have to move the screen using segue on the `main page`. However, even if the `segue name`, `TableViewController`, and `TableViewCell` name are correctly entered, the `data value` does `not pass`. I've solved this problem myself before. But on the main page, I don't know what the reason is, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

**mycode(ViewController)**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
    var rankValue: [BoardRank]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    NetworkHandler.getRankList() { rankValue in  // Code to load api value
        self.rankValue = rankValue               // Code to load api value
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "rankSegue" {
            let rankTableVC = segue.destination as! RankTableVC
            rankTableVC.rank = rankValue
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**RankTableVC**
[image]

**RankTableViewCell**
[image]

**jsonCode**

[image]

Comment: Let me guess. `rankTableVC.rank = rankValue` is really called (you can check with a Breakpoint or a print). `self.rankValue = rankValue` is really called too. BUT `getRankList() {}` is ASYNCHRONE, so if you add the prints `print("Rank in getRankList: \(self.rankValue)`, just before the line `self.rankValue = rankValue` AND, add a `print("Inside the segue: \(rankValue)")` before `rankTableVC.rank = ...`, you should see the issue: rankValue` in the `prepareForSegue()` code is nil, no? AND is it called BEFORE or AFTER the other added print? Which one do you think would have printed first?

Comment: The embed segue will fire when the view controller is loaded, but it takes time to fetch `rankValue` from the network. You need to save the reference to the embedded view controller in a property so that you can set `rankValue` and reload the tableview once the network operation is done.

Comment: I couldn't answer because there were no notifications. If the segue is executed first and the network is executed, the ```ViewController``` executes immediately. If you put the network value in the ```function```, the network is executed and the segue value is passed? - Paulw11

Comment: Larme, I tried the way you told me, but I'm not sure if I haven't fully understood it yet. ```self.rankValue = rankValue``` This code is specified and ```print("Inside the segue: \(rankValue)")``` is the same as the question I posted and the data is not passed.

Comment: The ```function``` Paulw11 is talking about is ```ex) let test: Void = ({ () -> Void in print("") })().```